# Referencing attributes from within a Chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, string-interpolation, chef-attributes

I have an attribute file titled `default.rb` with a key in it `default['current']` that stores a dir in string format. I wanted to use this for the following command to use when it changes directories:

```
# Run database migrations
execute 'database migrations' do
  user    'ubuntu'
  cwd     "#{default['current']}"
  command 'sudo php artisan down && sudo php artisan migrate --force && sudo php artisan up'
end
```

Instead when i ran the recipe i got the following error.

```
NameError
---------
No resource, method, or local variable named `default' for `Chef::Recipe "deploy"'
```

Is there a proper way to do this that I'm missing? I'd rather not hard code in the working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When attributes are referenced in a recipe, we need to prefix them with `node`, like this:

```
cwd     node['current']
```

---

See also: [Overriding attributes in the recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619001/overriding-attributes-in-the-recipe)

Comment: Yep, this worked for me. I had thought that default was just short hand for node.default.

Comment: In a recipe, node["variable"]  doesn't necessarily get the default

Comment: @JonMalachowski would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @coderanger - thanks for chiming in.  OP said `node.default['current']` did work.  Can you please update the answer to clarify that?

Comment: That refers specifically to the default level, which is one of 10 levels that attribute data can be set at.

Comment: Also you don't need quotes for a single value

Comment: Thanks.  I think enclosing in single quotes is just a matter of style - having them regardless of whether the string has a space or not, I feel, is a good thing.  Do you agree?

Comment: It's a matter of style to the degree that it's not a functional error but if you think that's a good style then all I can say is all the automated lint tools we have will disagree with you. Your call if you want to listen :)

Comment: @coderanger What would be your opinion on using symbols as keys instead?

Comment: We recommend strings because they are clearer to people not familiar with Ruby.

Comment: There is literally no difference between symbols and strings in chef- just be consistent for readability purposes. Symbols are one less character :-)

Comment: @JonMalachowski - +1 on your preference for symbols.  That one less character makes a difference when there are nested attributes.  I believer Chef has a dot notation for nested attributes but they are not recommending it.

Comment: @JonMalachowski I agree with your preference to symbols in that it is one less character to type, but I do not think it is safe to say that there is no difference between symbols and strings. They are fundamentally different objects treated very differently in memory. http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_symbols.html

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be answered. But I didn't see a link to the core of the documentation for this(IMO)
It is all here: https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html

Comment: I appreciate this but it also brings me back to a question i asked in the confirmed answer. I had thought that `default['attribute']` was the same as `node.default['attribute']` and according to the docs, `node` is implied if not included, so why did I need to include `node` in order for me to reference that attribute? For the record, I was able to accomplish the reference with node.default['attribute'] which was the given answer before the it was update to `node['attribute']`.

Comment: when using a variable in a recipe (reading it), you should use 'node["attribute"]', this allows the variable to be over written in the environment/role/cli etc

When the attribute is defined in the environment/variable/recipe defaults you choose what level you are defining it at.

At run time the final node attribute hashmap is computed by loading them in successive order [listed in that link]